# Angular how to make nested form array act independently

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to solve the problem of having my field change on both form array fields when you change the field type.

[image]

As you can see in the image. When I select the left field first name the right field changes to a text field. But when a add a new field it generates a dropdown field to the right and changes the top one as well. How do I make these fields act independently?

I also think the problem is the ngTemplate function I am using to check to see if the field is a option or text field. maybe this is a global within the form I am using, if that makes sense?

Html

```html
<div class="filter-wrapper">
  <form [formGroup]="usersForm" (ngSubmit)="onSearch()">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let userFormGroup of usersForm.controls.users.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroup]="userFormGroup" class="filter-form">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
          <mat-form-field class="form-toggle input-half dialog-dropdown">
            <mat-select formControlName="columnOptions">
              <mat-option value="null">
                -- none --
              </mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let formOption of displayedOptions" [value]="formOption.name" (click)="getOptionData(formOption.name)">
                {{formOption.title}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>

          <span class="match-txt">matches</span>
          <mat-form-field class="input dialog-dropdown">
            <ng-container *ngIf="selectedOpt.options?.length > 0; else inputField">
              <mat-select formControlName="columnValues">
                <mat-option value="null">
                  -- none --
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let formOption of selectedOpt.options" [value]="formOption.display_long_value || formOption.description">
                  {{ formOption.display_long_value || formOption.description }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #inputField>
              <input matInput type="text" formControlName="columnValues">
            </ng-template>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="action-btns">
          <mat-icon (click)="addFormControl()">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>

          <ng-container *ngIf="i !== 0">
            <mat-icon (click)="removeFormControl(i)">remove_circle_outline</mat-icon>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </form>
</div>
```

Form builder

```js
this.usersForm = this.fb.group({
  users: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      columnOptions: ['', Validators.required],
      columnValues: ['', Validators.required],
    }),
  ])
})
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l7stwq

Comment: Fiddle is broken, you haven't added './constants/adjustment-detail-columns'

Answer (score 0):

The stackblitz wasn't working because the import was missing to initialize columnOption/columnValues, but I think you should reference the formgroups created by your array. I usually start by logging the formgroup.value every step of the way to make sure My ui matches my data model, But try this:

change

```
<div [formGroup]="userFormGroup" class="filter-form">
```

to

```
  <div [formGroupName]="i" class="filter-form">
```

This should match with what your model would be showing for the formArray (since 
the groups have index-based names, per them being 'arrays'.

Hopefully this gets you somewhere, If you could update the stackblitz to be able to run I'd do some trial and error to see where I get

Good luck/Happy Coding!